# Can you have a print only version of an image?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need a color image appear when a user views the form in Lotus Notes. I need a black and white version of the same image to appear when the form is being printed.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is (as you probably already have found out) not possible using the standard hide/when options, because you can not only hide when printed.

Instead you should create a print friendly version of the form and create a button that opens the document with the print friendly form when the document must be printed. Have a look at the `@Command( [SwitchForm] ; formName )` Formula command for simple form switching.

Comment: Actually, in 8.5 I believe you can hide when printed.  I am testing it right now.

Comment: Ah... but the problem is that you can't hide only when reading.  As soon as you click the hide-when-reading box, the hide-when-printing box is also selected.

Comment: Exactly, Richard. Using the hide/when properties was my initial idea on how to solve it (until I saw that you can not just select When Printed).

Comment: You would think that with the proliferation of at-IsDocBeing's that they would eventually include at-IsDocBeingPrinted, right?

Comment: I was hoping for a miracle : )

I also looked for @IsBeingPrinted and didn't find anything. This definitely should be added.